# open new window using c# codebehind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am trying to open a new window from my codebehind page and for some odd reason it is not working as expected. From what I have searched, the two common methods are:

```
1.  Using Response.Redirect
2.  Page.Client.RegisterStartupScript
```

I have a string variable that is used for the URL or file name. To help you understand what I am doing, I have someone download a resource from the site. When they click on the link for the resource (it is a file or site link) I take them to a processing page where I see if they have the permissions to access the file and record they accessed it. Once done with this they will either be directed out to the site or receive the download file.

I use a string for the name. The two ways I have tried this are:

```
string sPageRedirect = 
     "<script type=\"text/javascript\" >window.open(' " + sFileName + "');</script>";

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Openwindow", String.Format(sPageRedirect),true);
```

When this method is used. My process page (trackdownload) simply sits there blank with the file information

```
Response.Redirect(sPageRedirect);
```

When this method is used I get a file not found error. When I look at the URL, it appears to append it so I get:

```
mysite/downloads/%3Cscript%20type=%22text/javascript%22%20%3Ewindow.open('%20http://mysite/myhelp/gotothis.htm');%3C/script%3E
```

**Update**

First, thank you YK1, Yuck and Kostas ch. for answering the question. This was my first post and I wanted to make sure I was doing my homework first and providing the details. I hope to be able to answer questions as well!  I kept playing with this and I came up with an alternate solution that I thought I would share. First as you point out, for what I wanted to do, it couldn’t be done as I had hoped. Because when a person clicked on a hyperlink to download the file or get directed to a new page that would open in a new window while still recording the download, it failed on opening the new window.  My goal was to record all help links gone to and files downloaded. So the file processing works as it always has and I’m happy with that. The solution I did was based off of Yuck’s idea. So what I am doing is

If the link is a file I go to my tracking page as I did before.

If the link is a web link, I have modified the href to use a JS call. Basically what Yuck had suggested. On the processing page, I am still doing the recording but I have added logic to read the last 4 characters (i.e. .htm) and if the file that was clicked on was that, the tracking page redirects itself back to the calling page.  This way, to the user, they are still on the primary web site and they get a new window that has their help files. The reason we can do the window.open is they are trained to expect it for those files so I shouldn’t have any issues with the users.

So on my codebehind I do this

```
if (dsData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["filetype"].ToString().Trim() == ".html" )
                                    {
                                        sClick = " onclick=\"openNew('" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"].ToString() +  dsData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["fileandpath"].ToString().Trim() + "')\"";
                                   }
                                    cell.InnerHtml = "<a href=\"downloads\\tracker.aspx?File=" + dsData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["file"].ToString
+ "\"" + sClick + ">" + dsData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["name"].ToString().Trim() + "</a>";
```

On my page it has this

```
function openNew(sLink) {
            window.open(sLink);
        }
```

Comment: Is Openwindow a defined JavaScript method in one of your JS files?

Comment: That `string.Format` doesn't seem to do a whole lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in the code behind because it needs to affect the browser. You could try by using jQuery and some variable from ASP .NET:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        window.open('<%: sFileName :>');
    });

</script>
```

This will immediately open a window upon document ready. Note that this will be particularly annoying for your users so I'm not sure where or why you'd want to use it. You may also run into trouble with pop-up blockers.

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
 Page.ResolveUrl("~/Pages/sPageRedirect.aspx")
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you have explicitly provided script block and also passed last parameter to  true. Change it to this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Openwindow", sPageRedirect, false);
```

Second case, you cant redirect to javascript :)
You redirect to an address:

```
Response.Redirect(sFileName);
```

Anyway, yes, you will have issues with popup blockers. Automatic popups are not desirable.